# pandas read json not working on MultiIndex

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read in a dataframe created via `df.to_json()` via `pd.read_json` but I'm getting a `ValueError`. I think it may have to do with the fact that the index is a MultiIndex but I'm not sure how to deal with that.

The original dataframe of 55k rows is called `psi` and I created `test.json` via:

```
psi.head().to_json('test.json')
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/olgabot/9897953#file-test_df-txt)is the output of `print psi.head().to_string()` if you want to use that.

When I do it on this small set of data (5 rows), I get a `ValueError`.

```
! wget --no-check-certificate https://gist.githubusercontent.com/olgabot/9897953/raw/c270d8cf1b736676783cc1372b4f8106810a14c5/test.json
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json('test.json')
```

Here's the full stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1de2f0e65268> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system(u' wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/olgabot/9897953/raw/c270d8cf1b736676783cc1372b4f8106810a14c5/test.json'>)
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 pd.read_json('test.json')

/home/obot/virtualenvs/envy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit)
    196         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
    197                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 198                           date_unit).parse()
    199 
    200     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

/home/obot/virtualenvs/envy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in parse(self)
    264 
    265         else:
--> 266             self._parse_no_numpy()
    267 
    268         if self.obj is None:

/home/obot/virtualenvs/envy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    481         if orient == "columns":
    482             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 483                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    484         elif orient == "split":
    485             decoded = dict((str(k), v)

ValueError: No ':' found when decoding object value

> /home/obot/virtualenvs/envy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py(483)_parse_no_numpy()
    482             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 483                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    484         elif orient == "split":
```

But when I do it on the whole dataframe (55k rows) then I get an [invalid pointer error](https://gist.github.com/olgabot/9897953#file-whole_df_invalid_pointer-txt) and the IPython kernel dies. Any ideas?

EDIT: added how the json was generated in the first place.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  I would imagine the problem was with how it was created in the first place.  Do you have sample code for creating it?

Comment: not Implemented, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4889

Comment: @Jeff: It still seems bad if `to_json` is generating invalid JSON.  Is that what's happening, or is there some other error here?

Comment: well this is *reading* it. welcome to have a PR to fix it (though its a bit non-trivial).

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, but she says she created the JSON with `to_json` (but doesn't show exactly how).

Comment: oh right....well its not-implemented / supported ATM, so, just reset the index first. In theory it should raise a NotImplementedError until it IS implemented. Would take a PR for that too.

Comment: my bad, added how the JSON was generated in the first place and added txt of the dataframe in case you want to use it. I agree that trying to do `to_json` should raise a `NotImplementedError` and suggest to do `reset_index()` first as Jeff said below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not implemented ATM, see the issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4889.

You can simply reset the index first, e.g

```
df.reset_index().to_json(...)
```

and it will work.

Comment: it is not working on pandas 1.3.0 i am getting the error `NotImplementedError: orient='table' is not supported for MultiIndex columns` when using `df.reset_index().to_json(orient="table")`

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just write json with orient = 'table'

`df.to_json(path_or_buf='test.json', orient='table')`

read multi_index json

`pd.read_json('test.json', orient='table')`

Comment: it loaded table full of NaN for me=( But with the same MultiIndex structure as initial df has.

Comment: Getting `NotImplementedError: orient='table' is not supported for MultiIndex` in pandas 1.0.1

Comment: I believe with pandas v1+, you need to provide `typ == 'frame'` and then it accepts orient table.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html?highlight=read_json

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return MultiIndex structure:

```
 # save MultiIndex indexes names 
 indexes_names = df.index.names

 df.reset_index().to_json('dump.json')

 # return back MultiIndex structure:
 loaded_df = pd.read_json('dump.json').set_index(indexes_names)
```

Comment: If you use names on a series it will make a frozen set that is only level 1. This works if you simply do something like:
`pd.read_json('series.json').set_index(series.index)`

Answer (score 0):

this was my simple dirty fix for encoding/decoding multiindex pandas dataframe which seems to also work for datetime in index/columns... not optimized!

here is the encoder to json - I encoder the dataframe, index and columns into a dict to create a json

```
import json
import pandas as pd

def to_json_multiindex(df):
    dfi = df.index.to_frame()
    dfc = df.columns.to_frame()

    d = dict(
        df = df.to_json(),
        di = dfi.to_json(),
        dc = dfc.to_json()   
    )

    return json.dumps(d)
```

meanwhile here is the decoder which reads the json dict and re-creates the dataframe

```
def read_json_multiindex(j):
    d = json.loads(j)

    di=pd.read_json(d['di'])
    if di.shape[1]>1:
        di = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(di)
    else:
        _name = di.columns[0]
        di = di.index
        di.name = _name
        
        
    dc=pd.read_json(d['dc'])
    if dc.shape[1]>1:
        dc = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dc)
    else:
        _name = dc.columns[0]
        dc = dc.index
        dc.name = _name        
    
    df = pd.read_json(d['df']).values
    
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=df,
        index=di,
        columns=dc,
    )
```

and here is a test for multiindex columns and index... seems to preserve the dataframe. Couple of issues 1) probably inefficient and 2) does seem to work for datatime in multiindex (but works when it isn't multiindex)

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data = [[0,1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]],
        index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
           (('aa','bb'),('aa','cc'),('bb','cc')
        ),
        names=['AA','BB']),
        columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
           (('XX','YY'),('XX','ZZ'),('YY','ZZ')
        ),
        names=['YY','ZZ'])
    )
    
    j = to_json_multiindex(df)
    d = read_json_multiindex(j)
```