# something wrong with dataframe.to_json()

Tags: python, json, pandas

my dataframe l is like this:

```
                            0    1
Sepal Length  Label     
(4.296, 5.2]  setosa        39   0.866667
              versicolor     5   0.111111
              virginica      1   0.022222
(5.2, 6.1]    setosa        11   0.220000
              versicolor    29   0.580000
              virginica     10   0.200000
(6.1, 7]      versicolor    16   0.372093
              virginica     27   0.627907
(7, 7.9]      virginica     12   1.000000
```

and then excute  ll=l.to_json()  ,the result is:

```
'{"0":{"["(4.296, 5.2]","setosa"]":39,"["(4.296, 5.2]","versicolor"]":5,"["(4.296, 5.2]","virginica"]":1,"["(5.2, 6.1]","setosa"]":11,"["(5.2, 6.1]","versicolor"]":29,"["(5.2, 6.1]","virginica"]":10,"["(6.1, 7]","versicolor"]":16,"["(6.1, 7]","virginica"]":27,"["(7, 7.9]","virginica"]":12},"1":{"["(4.296, 5.2]","setosa"]":0.8666666667,"["(4.296, 5.2]","versicolor"]":0.1111111111,"["(4.296, 5.2]","virginica"]":0.0222222222,"["(5.2, 6.1]","setosa"]":0.22,"["(5.2, 6.1]","versicolor"]":0.58,"["(5.2, 6.1]","virginica"]":0.2,"["(6.1, 7]","versicolor"]":0.3720930233,"["(6.1, 7]","virginica"]":0.6279069767,"["(7, 7.9]","virginica"]":1.0}}'
```

then i try to read the ll, do pd.read_json(ll) and failed. the following is the message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-574-4cb1a3ab2e3c> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_json(l1g)

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines)
    279         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
    280                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 281                           date_unit).parse()
    282 
    283     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in parse(self)
    347 
    348         else:
--> 349             self._parse_no_numpy()
    350 
    351         if self.obj is None:

/home/lv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    564         if orient == "columns":
    565             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 566                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    567         elif orient == "split":
    568             decoded = dict((str(k), v)

ValueError: No ':' found when decoding object value
```

i want to save the data's struct of multiIndex ,so how to do

can anyone help me?thanks  >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas json export and roundtrip still have difficulty with MultiIndex (according to [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4889))

One way to solve this would be to do a `reset_index` before the export and a `set_index` afterwards, as mentioned in the github issue and [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768931/1562285)

Did you try one of the other `orient`'s ([pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html))

Comment: after do a reset_index seems to be what i want . btw, i mainly transport the json to d3.js, hopely it works with the reset_index form.  whatever , thanks a lot.